# Only use value in method when value is available in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using the aslsx gem in Rails to generate Excel files.

In my template I have:

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Buttons") do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ['Id', 'Data', 'Passenger']
    @rides.each do |ride|
        sheet.add_row [ride.id, ride.date, ride.passenger.name]
    end
end
```

Problem is that some rides do not have a passenger and so the .name method fails.
How I can make sure to only use the name method when a ride exists?

I tried:

```
sheet.add_row [ride.id, ride.date, ride.passenger.name if ride.passenger]
```

But this did not work.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply do

```
sheet.add_row [ride.id, ride.date, ride.passenger.try(:name)]
```

This will return nil if there is no passenger and the passenger's name when there is a passenger.

More info on the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/try).

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's pretty flexible, but in situations like this you can't use `if`. Instead you have two options.

For newer (2.3+) versions of Ruby you can use the conditional navigation operator:

```
[ride.id, ride.date, ride.passenger&.name]
```

Or for older ones:

```
[ride.id, ride.date, ride.passenger && ride.passenger.name]
```

Normally `x && y` is *roughly* equivalent to `y if x`.

Comment: I like this part `ride.passenger&.name`. Could you share a source, where i can find these new features.

Comment: It's called a [safe navigation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator).

Answer (score 1):

You can go oldest extra line if option.

```
name = ride.passenger ? ride.passenger.name : ""
sheet.add_row [ride.id, ride.date, name]

#OR
sheet.add_row [ride.id, ride.date, ride.passenger ? ride.passenger.name : ""]
```